# Hack to save lync conversation even if admin turns off saving lync conversations?

Tags: lync

My team uses lync to send information and it annoys me we cannot save conversations.  Does anyone know of a solution that does this client-side?  Just appending the text to files named after the user would be good enough for me!

If not I will probably look into the lync SDK and try to code up something myself.

Comment: Could this and the linked question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14300803) be combined in someway. They appear to be asking for the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Try this https://github.com/bujocek/LyncIMLocalHistory. I've used the Tom Morgans answer from the suggested link and created own local lync conversation history tracker. You can either build it from source or just unpack and run latest release here: https://github.com/bujocek/LyncIMLocalHistory/releases